# OnFocusChange not always working

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

In one of my activities I have three `EditText`s and an OK button. The `OnFocusChangeListener` is set to all three `EditText`s. The listener should trigger every time the focus is lost.

Switching between `EditText`s works perfectly. But if the user presses the OK button there's no focus change (losing the focus) triggered for the `EditText` the user focused before pressing the button.

What's wrong with my code?

```
private class MyOnFocusChangeListener implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    private EditText editText;

    public MyOnFocusChangeListener(final EditText editText) {
        super();

        this.editText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(final View view, final boolean isFocused) {
        if (!isFocused) {
            if (editText == editText1) {
                // Do a calculation
            } else if (editText == editText2) {
                // Do another calculation
            } else if (editText == editText3) {
                // Do a different calculation
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
    // ...
    editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new MyOnFocusChangeListener(editText1));
    editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new MyOnFocusChangeListener(editText2));
    editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new MyOnFocusChangeListener(editText3));
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to clear the focus when user click on OK or other button....

e.g.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
 {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
     {
          editText1.clearfocus();
          editText2.clearfocus();
          editText3.clearfocus();
          ....
     }
 }
```

Comment: This would possibly trigger OnFocusChange on all three EditText so I can't use it. But this helped me to find a better way. I now store the EditText that get's the focus in a class member and on OnClick of the button I clear the focus of that particular EditText. That works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using: [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)(..) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could be having issues with touch mode, from the [android docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2008/12/touch-mode.html):

"The relationship between touch mode, selection, and focus means you must not rely on selection and/or focus to exist in your application."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is really bad because I do have to chose between two bad scenarios. 1.) A calcualtion only takes place if the user enters a different EditText before hitting the OK button (buttons are not focusable per default). 2.) Change button to focusable so that the user has to hit the button twice. The latter works better than the first because the user might store uncalculated values in 1.).

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink the design of your app slightly, what exactly is it trying to do? You could be over complicating your code, when a redesign could help solve your problem. Also your code has some problems, you don't need to create a focus listener and pass the edittext to the constructor. When onFocusChanged is called it will pass you the view whose focus changed, just cast the view parameter to an edit text (check its type first!).

Comment: Link gives: "Error 404 - File not found".

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @dong221, and incorporating the comment made by @Harald, one way to clear the focus without having to keep track of the last selected `EditText` is to get a reference to the `currentFocus` from the `window` object. Something like this:

```
myDoneButton.setOnClickListener { v -> 
    // Assuming we are in an Activity, otherwise get a reference to the Activity first
    window.currentFocus?.clearFocus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you bind onFocusChangeListener to the view element you want to be observed

```
editText.onFocusChangeListener = this
editText.setOnClickListener(this)
```

by keyword `this` it means the `ViewHolder` class