# ScrollTo() does not work eventhough "adjustResize" is used

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I have a screen which fits to viewport and hence does not show a scrollbar by default.

It has some TextView elements, a EditText and a CheckBox below the EditText. My objective is to scroll and show CheckBox element when EditText control is in focus. When EditText is in focus, the screen becomes scrollable since I have "adjustResize" set for the activity.

Now here is the code which is trying to scroll:

```
mEditTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            final ScrollView mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

            if (hasFocus){

                if(mScrollView != null) {
                    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });

                }

            }
       }
```

And this does not scroll to the bottom. it just brings focus onto the soft keyboard and the checkbox is hidden behind it.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

PS: My guess here is Even after 'adjustResize', Android still thinks that there is no scope for scrolling and hence does not scroll. this could be the case here?

Comment: Will this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427506/onfocuschange-not-always-working
Basically try clearing focus of the edit text once, then scroll and set focus

Comment: Or you could do this `mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mainScrollView.getBottom());` in the run() method

Answer (score 0):

How you tried to invoke the `fullScroll()` directly instead of `post`ing a runnable? I think that this might be the problem, because `post()` just adds your wish of the scrollview to scroll to the message queue, and probably the message queue is not worked while the textview has the focus and the softkeyboard is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the method `scrollTo(x,y)`? I used it, it's perfect. Just use `Handler` send a delay message,use this method when you receive the message.